# jQuery to group a list alphabetically

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<ul id="recipes">
<li><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
<li><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
<li><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
<li><a href='xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

That I need to convert to a list grouped alphabetically like this:

```
<h3>A<h3>
<ul>
<li><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
<li><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>B<h3>
<ul>
<li><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>C<h3>
<ul>
<li><a href=''xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've sorted the list with jQuery, but can't quite figure out how to achieve the grouping I need, can anyone help?

EDIT: I can add more info to my original list, so it looks like this:

```
<ul id="recipes">
<li class='a'><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
<li class='a'><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
<li class='b'><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
<li class='c'><a href='xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

I suspect that will help a lot

Comment: why do you want these at the UI , while displaying data from server , you should do these type of stuff

Comment: I wouldn't use javascript for reorganizing your DOM like this.  I would do it server side.

Comment: It's a limitation of the platform I'm working on, I can only do this on the front end in jQuery.

Comment: What do you have so far? How does the behavior differ from what you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var headings = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

var $recipes = $('#recipes').detach();
$.each(headings, function(){
    $('body').append('<h3>' + this + '</h3>');
    $('body').append($('<ul/>').append($recipes.find('.' + this)));
});
```

example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8khZ/1/)

Comment: Awesome :) I actually found another solution a bit after yours (will add for reference) but this does it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I figured out which works similarly:

```
var letters = [ "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z" ];
$.each(letters, function(idx,val) {
    $("li." + val).wrapAll("<div><h3>" + val.toUpperCase() + "</h3><ul></ul></div>");
});
```