# jQuery add class corresponding to the first letter in list item

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<ul id="recipes">
    <li><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to add classes with jQuery like this:

```
<ul id="recipes">
    <li class="a"><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
    <li class="a"><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
    <li class="c"><a href='xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

The goal is to group the list aphabetically using the answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4891572/3215381) which requires the classes to be added first.

Comment: Hi there! What have you tried? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#recipes li").each(function() { // <-- Run over each li
  var s = $(this).find("a").html().charAt(0) // <-- takes the first character of link
  $(this).addClass(s.toLowerCase()) // <-- Add the character as a class to the li
})
```

```js
$("#recipes li").each(function() {
  var s = $(this).find("a").html().charAt(0)
  $(this).addClass(s.toLowerCase())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="recipes">
    <li><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use `s.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC Thanks, added

Comment: I tested this solution with success, thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can loop each `li` and get first letter of `a` that is inside and transform it to lowercase

```js
$('ul li').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass($(this).find('a').text()[0].toLowerCase())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="recipes">
    <li><a href='xxx'>Apple Pie</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Almond Slice</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Banana Cake</a></li>
    <li><a href='xxx'>Carrot Cake</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the list in a variable, loop through the variable and add a class as the substring of the text value of each member of the list.

```
var baked = $("#recipes li").get();

for(var i = 0; i<baked.length, i++;){
  var currentBaked = $(baked[i]).get('a');
  currentBaked.parent().addClass(currentBaked.text().substring(0,1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below listed code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("ul > li").each(function () {
     var text = $(this).find("a").text();
     $(this).addClass(text[0].toLowerCase());
   });
});
```